# within a dictionary, how do I remove a value from a key with multiple values? Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def main():
    dictionary = OrderedDict()
    dictionary["one"] = ["hello", "blowing"]
    dictionary["two"] = ["frying", "goodbye"]

    for key in dictionary:
        print key, dictionary[key]

    user_input = raw_input("REMOVE BUILDINGS ENDING WITH ING? Y/N")
    if user_input == ("y"):
        print ""
        for key in dictionary:
            for x in dictionary[key]:
                if ("ING") in x or ("ing") in x:
                    del dictionary[key][x]

    print ""

    for key in dictionary:
        print key, dictionary[key]

main()
```

I am attempting to remove any item with "ing" in it from all keys within a dictionary, example "blowing" from the key "one" and "frying" from the key "two".

The resulting dictionary would go from this:

```
one ['hello', 'blowing'], two ['frying', 'goodbye']
```

to this:

```
one ['hello'], two ['goodbye']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dict comprehension.

```
return {x : [i for i in dictionary[x] if not i.lower().endswith('ing')] for x in dictionary}
```

Edited to replace values ending with 'ing' with 'removed'

```
return {x : [i if not i.lower().endswith('ing') else 'removed' for i in dictionary[x]] for x in dictionary}
```

Comment: Ok this works nice, can you rework it instead replace that value with "removed"

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
{key: [ele for ele in val if not ele.lower().endswith('ing')] for key, val in d.items()}
```

**Explanation:**

Start from the right,

- `d` is the dictionary, it stores `<key, [val]>`
- for each `key, val` in `d` we do the following,
- `[ele for ele in val if not ele.lower().endswith('ing')]` means for every element(`ele`) in list(`val`) we perform the operations :

  - convert each string to lower case
  - check if it ends-with `ing'
  - then if none of these(`if not`) then get `ele`
- Then you just print `{ key: [ele1, ele2, ..] , .. }`.

Comment: Exact duplicate of my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in an immutable fashion (i.e., without mutating the original dict) by using a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```py
>>> d = {'one': ['hello', 'blowing'], 'two': ['frying', 'goodbye']}
>>> {k: [w for w in v if not w.lower().endswith('ing')] for k, v in d.items()}
{'one': ['hello'], 'two': ['goodbye']}
```

Comment: can you explain what this does?

Comment: `{k: ... for k, v in d.items()}` is a dict comprehension, it creates dict with the same keys but altered values. For each key `k` and value `v` we iterate over all words `w` in `v`, create a new list that contains all such `w` that their lowered version doesn't end with "ing", and then use this list as a new value in the new dict.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> collections.OrderedDict({key:filter(lambda x:not x.endswith('ing'), value) for key,value in dictionary.items()})
OrderedDict([('two', ['goodbye']), ('one', ['hello'])])
```

Answer (score -1):

You were trying to delete with string index not int position reference. Here is the modified code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def main():
    dictionary = OrderedDict()
    dictionary["one"] = ["hello", "blowing"]
    dictionary["two"] = ["frying", "goodbye"]

    for key in dictionary:
        print key, dictionary[key]

    user_input = raw_input("REMOVE BUILDINGS ENDING WITH ING? Y/N")
    if user_input == ("y"):
        print ""
        for key,value in dictionary.iteritems():
            for i,x  in enumerate(value):
                if ("ING") in x or ("ing") in x:
                    del dictionary[key][i]

    print ""

    for key in dictionary:
        print key, dictionary[key]

main()
```

Comment: This won't work if there are multiple -ing in one list.

Comment: Oh yes, it wont work fine in that case. User has asked query regarding the shared code , hence it is only meant for tat. so, that he/she can get a understanding of what was wrong.